# JSON to CSV converter with style using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, css, csv

I am converting my JSON to CSV using the below-mentioned function, I want to know if there is a way to send style to my CSV file. I need background color for header, Border for all the cells and Auto-column adjustment.

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {

            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "Report_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

This is the function I am using to for CSV generation with all the details mentioned in the comments after each step.
If you have any doubts please ask freely any type of suggestion will be valuable to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSV it just a comma separated rows of values. so there is no styling its only values. This csv file is readable in any text editor. If you mean to say, you want to see it in Excel with header rows or data with some styling then instead of csv, you will need to use js module which will produce Excel file like js2excel, SheetJS